# How do merged lookahead sets help LALR parse more grammars than SLR?

Tags: parsing

From what I have searched on Google so far, the only difference between LALR(1) and SLR(1) is that LALR(1) uses states with merged lookahead sets. One source says that LALR(1) won't run into shift-reduce conflicts because the parser will "remember" from which state it arrived at the current state. However, there are no differences in the parsing algorithm, so I'm having trouble seeing how these merged lookahead sets would help the LALR parser resolve shift-reduce conflicts. And if the parser remembers from which state it arrived at the current state, why is it still vulnerable to reduce-reduce conflicts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually SLR which uses merged lookahead sets. Or, more accurately, the lookahead set for each *production* in an SLR parse table is approximated as the FOLLOW set for the last symbol in the production, effectively ignoring the context.

LALR parsers have merged *states* with respect to canonical LR parsers. In both LR and LALR, in contrast to SLR, tbe lookahead sets are computed accurately, but in the case of the LALR parser, the states are merged so that it has the same states (but not the same lookahead sets) as tbe SLR parser.

There is a reasonable discussion of the differences in the Wikipedia articles on SLR parsing, LALR parsing and Canonical LR parsing. See the references for those articles for more information.

No matter which parser-generation technique you use, there will be conflicts if the grammar requires more lookahead. For example, the following grammar requires two lokahead symbols to decide whether to shift or reduce a `NAME`:

```
prog → λ
prog → prog defn
defn → NAME :
defn → defn NAME
```

Here, a NAME is part of a `defn` if it is not followed by a colon, so to decide whether or not to shift a NAME, you need not just the NAME, which is the lookahead token, but also tge following token, the second lookahead.

---

Here is a very simple grammar which is not SLR(1), which might possibly illuminate the problem with using follow sets. (It comes straight out of the Dragon book, and is often used as an example of why SLR(1) grammars are inadequate):

```
S → L = R
S → R
L → id
L → * R
R → L
```

Here, the FOLLOW sets of R and L are identical. Both R and L include `=`, since `* R = ...` is valid, and will reduce to `L = ...`, and clearly both R and L can appear at the end of an S, so both FOLLOW sets include the end-of-input marker.

The problem then is to decide whether or not to reduce `R → L`. In `L = R`, we should leave the `L` as is and shift the `=`. But the FOLLOW sets don't help, because `R` can be followed by `=`. So in an SLR(1) grammar, which only uses FOLLOW sets, there is a shift/reduce conflict in the state:

```
S → L • = R
R → L •
```

This conflict doesn't exist in the LALR(1) grammar because in that state
the lookahead set for the production `R → L` does not include `=`, because the production was included from the item `S → • R`, whose lookahead is the end-of-input marker.

Comment: SLR effectively uses the follow set for the last symbol in the production. LALR uses merged states that essentially combine lookahead sets. Wouldn't this mean that SLR and LALR are the same, only difference being that LALR makes its lookahead sets explicit? Wikipedia just says that LALR uses more rules to resolve conflicts, but does not specify any specific rule differences.

Comment: @np: no, it doesn't mean that. In a given state, not every element of the FOLLOW set is a feasible lookahead symbol. This matters because a reduction is only possible if the lookahead symbol is in the lookahead set for the rule to be reduced.

Comment: Ok, I think I get what you mean. Suppose for some production of a hypothetical grammar, the action is to shift for two of the lookahead tokens and reduce for the rest. LALR would be able to handle this grammar because it can have shift and reduce actions on the same row of the action/goto table, while SLR can't handle it because it can't have both actions on the same row. Am I correct in saying this?

Comment: @np: no, that's not it either. LR(0) can't use the lookahead. SLR(1) can use the lookahead, but it doesn't compute the lookahead sets accurately. So it can (and does) happen that a shiftable token is incorrectly added to the lookahead set for a reduction.

Comment: @npCompleteNoob: I added the standard example of a grammar which is not SLR(1), along with some explanation. It should be easy to find longer explanations; in particular, it is used in the Dragon book.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to figure out from that grammar how LALR is more powerful than SLR. So conceptually LALR is able to rule out some terminals in the FOLLOW set based on some specific productions. If we make action/goto tables, the LALR and SLR tables may differ by just a few entries, but those entries make the difference for some grammars?

Comment: Every action in an LALR table is also in the SLR table. However, the SLR table may have additional actions which result in conflicts. (It may also have additional actions which only result in error detection being delayed until after a reduction.) Since a single conflict makes a language unparseable (without some hack), even a single additional entry could make the difference.